# aggregating finer resolutions to lower ones using Pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data with 15 minute resolution as below:

```
year    rainfall(per 15 min)
2006    1
2006    1.2
2006    1.3
2006    0
```

Where I need to aggregate the second column as 30 min, 60 min, 1 hr, 2 hr, 6 hr, 12 hr, and 24 hr. I also want the corresponding years to be translated to the new aggregated matrices.

I was wondering if somebody could help me to do this using numPy or Pandas?

Comment: Could you post some actual code so we can see what the data looks like and what you've tried so far?

Comment: What does your output datafame look like?

Comment: The DataFrame is the same as what is shown above (with indeces as first col in pandas). I want to add every 4 values (15min) to get a rainfall time series of 1 hr resolution along with their corresponding years in col0.

Comment: Just for me to understand, each value represents the rainfall over 15 minutes but the time specification is years for each value.

Comment: yes thats right ... and I need the years since I am going to get Annual maximum series for each one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to `groupby` every 4 values and `sum()`

```
z=io.StringIO("""year    rainfall
2006    1
2006    1.2
2006    1.3
2006    0
2006    1
2006    1.2
2006    1.3
2006    0""")

df = pd.read_table(z,delim_whitespace=True)
```

Just

```
df.groupby([df.index // 4 * 4, 'year']).sum()

            rainfall
year    
0   2006    3.5
4   2006    3.5
```